# Сервер авторизации для линукс

Tags: ldap

Стоит задача иметь одну базу данных со всеми пользователями, которые могу авторизовываться на серверах без необходимости поддерживать актуальный список пользователей на каждом сервере. Должны быть возможность разрешить одной группе пользователей авторизовываться на одном сервер, но запретить, например, это на другом. Что посоветуете? Спасибо. Я так понимаю это LDAP сервер нам нужен?

Comment: Да, можно сделать LDAP в качестве хранилища юзеров, распределить юзеров по необходимым группам в LDAP (admins, dba, operator, etc), настроить все свои сервера на аутентификацию в LDAP-e с ограничением возможности логина определенным группам.

Comment: Настройка на сервере это настройка ssh сервера? Какой-то конкретный LDAP сервер посоветуете? Openldap подойдёт?

Comment: OpenLdap - да. Настройка на сервере - это настройка PAM для ssh, или групп в ssh (но в этом случае, думаю, будет задействован nsswitch.conf). В общем есть варианты. И самое главное - тренируйтесь это все делать на какой-нить тестовой виртуалочке, а то отрубите себе все возможности залогониться ; ]

Comment: Ок! Спасибо! Будем осторожны!